# How can I use SHOW CREATE TABLE in a subquery?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.`tables`
    JOIN (SHOW CREATE TABLE)  # <-- need help here
WHERE  table_schema LIKE 'tables\_%'
```

Is there a way to do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devart is correct that you can't join to the `SHOW CREATE` statement.
However, depending on your exact needs, you can spoof this by creating your own `SHOW CREATE` statement.

The complexity of the code will increase if you need to include the database engine, column and table collations, indexes, and so forth - however the SQL below will give you the right table and fields, complete with datatypes. I'm sure you can extend it further by examining the contents of `information_schema.columns` in more depth.

```
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `',t.TABLE_NAME,'` ',
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.COLUMN_NAME,' ',c.COLUMN_TYPE,' ',c.EXTRA) SEPARATOR ','),';') AS CreateStatement
FROM information_schema.tables t
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns c 
  ON t.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME
/* WHERE STATEMENT IF NEEDED */;
```

Sample output:

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` rowid int(11) auto_increment,
  id int(11) ,username varchar(200) ,answer varchar(2000) ;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that temporary tables won't be listed in `information_schema.tables`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ways to do it in this way. The `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command retrieves a data-set, but the result cannot be joined with another table. Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE` as a separate command for each table you need in the application.