# Tool to get CREATE TABLE statements from INNODB TABLE MONITOR OUTPUT?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have INNODB TABLE MONITOR OUTPUT and need to get CREATE TABLE statements from it.
Does anyone know a tool which can generate it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a tool that can generate it. Here's an example shell command that you can use to search for the names of tables and generate a series of SHOW CREATE TABLE commands:

```
grep '^TABLE: name .*/' <name-of-mysqld-error-log> | 
sed -e 's/^/SHOW CREATE /' -e 's/: name / `/' -e 's#/#`.`#' -e 's/,.*/`;/'
```

This should turn a line like this:

```
TABLE: name test/parent, id 0 13, columns 6, indexes 2, appr.rows 299
```

Into this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `test`.`parent`;
```

Then collect the output and run it as an SQL script.

Also you should be aware that the InnoDB monitor features activated by creating specially named tables is deprecated as of MySQL 5.6, and removed from the product in MySQL 5.7.

The new source of information is the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. See [How can I use SHOW CREATE TABLE in a subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716225/how-can-i-use-show-create-table-in-a-subquery) for an example of retrieving information from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Answer (score 0):

Not from the table monitor, but you can generate table structure from InnoDB dictionary:

https://twindb.com/recover-table-structure-from-innodb-dictionary/